# URL Routing (instead of subdomain routing) not working

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to set up a super simple reverse proxy with traefik for some stuff on my LAN with docker / docker-compose. The problem is because I don't have a domain name I'm trying to access (for example) the service "whoami" on the url (my server is stored on 192.168.1.2) "192.168.1.22/whoami". Most configs I've found set it up for something like "subdomain.domain.com." Here's my docker-compose:

```
services:


traefik:

image: traefik

container_name: traefik

command:

- "--api.insecure=true"

- "--providers.docker=true"

- "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"

- "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"

ports:

- 80:80

- 8080:8080

volumes:

- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"


whoami:

image whoami

container_name: whoami

labels:

- "traefik.enable=true"

- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`192.168.1.2`) && Path(`/whoami`)"

- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"

restart: unless-stopped
```

When I access 192.168.1.2:8080 the dashboard loads, but when I try to access 192.168.1.2/whoami it gives me this error: "Not Found. The URL you requested (/whoami) was not found. Generated by darkhttpd/1.12". However when I access other urls like 192.168.1.2/badurl it just throws the error "404 page not found."

If you need any more information feel free to ask and thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to your problem might be to use a domain in your host rules, and just add a host entry on your machine to direct the domain to the IP.

Also check on the dashboard that the router does actually register. And if not, Traefik logs on debug level are quite verbose about problems.